# Deploying Maven artifacts from Artifactory to WebLogic12c

Tags: java, maven, artifactory, weblogic12c

I am trying to deploy Maven artifacts from Artifactory to WebLogic12c, I did deploy to Artifactory, but not sure how they are getting deployed to the appserver.

I tried to use Weblogic Maven Plugin for that, without success.

What I am trying to achieve is automatic deployment, i.e. when a new artifact is deployed to Artifactory, it should be deployed to WebLogic too.

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "migrate". Do you want to deploy Artifactory in WebLogic or use WebLogic instead of Artifactory?

Comment: RiggsFolly Hello, Thanks for responding quickly. 
Sorry for not explain better. 
 when I deploy in Artifactory, i need add directly to WebLogic. 

Example: 

I have the file "A.jar" and file "B.war". I deploy in Artifactory and I want to see  "A.jar" and "B.war" in WebLogic12c (Deployments, may be?)

Thanks again

Comment: Hello again, 
I've been looking about  Hudson and I've installed. 
But this is not what I need. : (
Let me explain: 
- I have an Artifactory repository. 
- Each time deploy a file to Artifactory also has to appear in WebLogic12c.
- I need to migrate all artifacts to WebLogic12c.  !important CSS TICK :-)

Thanx!

Comment: I think I mentioned number of times that Hudson/Jenkins are **not** the tools you need? I can repeat it once more, if needed.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a deployment tool for that.

If you are proficient in DevOps tools like [chef](http://www.getchef.com/chef/)/[puppet](http://puppetlabs.com/)/[saltstack](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/index.html)/[ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home) etc. you can use them. If you look for something more usable without operations background, I highly recommend [LiveRebel by ZeroTurnaround](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/liverebel/).

All those tools will fetch the correct artifact from Artifactory (based on the logic you define, e.g. latest version, specific build, or based on specific properties, such as `QA.status=passed`) by using the [Artifactory REST API](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+REST+API) and then deploy it to WebLogic.

Comment: Thanks again, i have been watching Hudson too. Have seen tutorials about Hudson and WebLogic, Can serve for what I'm looking for?

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment to @carlspring's answer, although technically you can use CI server for deployment, it's not a good idea. Deployment tools should do deployment.

Comment: There is this proposal ongoing, i think you might be interested: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66151/devops you might be interested.

Answer (score -1):

Artifactory is an artifact repository manager. This means it's a store for artifacts. It's not a Continuous Deployment tool. You should consider a DevOp tool or write your own scripts that will deploy it for you, it's not something that comes out of the box or that you should be expecting from a repository manager.

Comment: Carl, how your answer is different from mine (except of lacking examples of deplyoment tools, of course)?

Comment: Thx for comment Carlspring, Can serve Hudson for what I'm looking for?

Comment: @JBaruch, as a developer of an artifact repository, I was hoping you'd mention what exactly an artifact repository manager is and what to expect from it.

Comment: @user3687179: Yes, Hudson can do it. If you'll be picking a continuous integration server, I'd recommend Jenkins instead.

Comment: Jenkins is better? Ok, I guess I have to continue this installation ([URL](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins)). So I  only need know how to implement it with Artifactory and i finish, not? 
Thank you very much for your help.


https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Installing+Jenkins

Comment: Guys, @carlspring, you can use CI server for deployment, but it's wrong. It's like keeping binaries in it. There are simple and straightforward tools for that. Which are made for that task and do it better than abused CI server. Please, use the right tools for the job.